# Загрузить несколько изображений с помощью PHP

Tags: php, header, download, multiple

Я хочу скачать несколько файлов одновременно с PHP. Я знаю, что это в формате ZIP. Но я хочу скачать все картинки одновременно.Код Foreach работает правильно. Скачивает только 1 фото. Как я могу загрузить все свои фотографии одновременно? (Без сжатия). Заранее вам благодарен

Мой index.php

```
<body>
<?php 
$array=[
    1=>'1.jpg',
    2=>'2.jpg',
    3=>'3.jpg',
    4=>'4.jpg',
    5=>'5.jpg'];
?>
<form action="download.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <?php
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) { ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $val ?>" width=200 height=100><br><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="id[<?php echo $key ?>]" value="<?php echo $val ?>"><br><br>
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="submit" name="download" value="Yüklə">
</form>
```

Мой download.php

```
if (isset($_POST['download'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key => $value) {
        $d=uniqid().".jpeg";
        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$d");
        readfile($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Как и написали - собрать все картинки в архив и скачать этот архив.

Answer (score 1):

Размножте запросы скачивания с помощью JS - откроется сразу несколько окон и скачается все что нужно, других вариантов скорее всего нет. По крайней мере тут так говорят: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339440/download-multiple-files-with-a-single-action